# Bedroom light switch now controls the whole upstairs

Tags: lighting

I wanted to change a light in my bedroom and I think I've wired it up a bit wrong because the upstairs lights only turn on now when my bedroom light is on. Before they were all working fine.
Any advise please?

Comment: We need much more information.  Right now it sounds like you change a light bulb and now have the problem.  Add pictures of the wires and lights you played with to your question.  Off hand would say both lights are on the same circuit, but you added the power wire for upstairs to the switch, instead of having it bypass.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.